# automatic mysql backup in windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, mysql, backup, database-restore, database-backup

someone Know and can recommend me an open source program or freeware software to realize automatics backups in mysql under windows server 2003.

I need automatize a task every day.

A shareware program for that is  http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Utilities/Backup_and_Copy_Utilities/MySQL_Auto_Backup.html, but I need a freeware version.

thare are any option??  thanks a lot.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's lots of options. But you've not really provided a lot of information about what you are trying to achieve, e.g. do you have a requirement to write the backup to something other than a conventional filesystem?

To minimise downtime (if that's important) you might consider running master-slave replication, and running the backup from the slave (which could reside on the same physical server) or keeping the data on a mirrored disk set, breaking the mirror and starting a secon instance of mysql to run the backup from (although this will break the files if you don't stop the database before breaking the mirror). But that doesn't really address of how you get the data out of the DBMS.

What are your objectives here? What sort of backup do you want? The quickest solution would be to grab images of the datafile - which only requires that the DBMS is shutdown to get a consistent image - then any file copying tool will work. If you have a huge amount of data then you might want to do incremental backups - in which case you might just configure a replication log and back up the replication logs relative to some datum.

OTOH if you want to extract the data and schema, then mysqldump comes as standard with mysqld. There's details of how to run it within a MSWindows batch file in the comments in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Remember that backups are useless unless you regularly test that you can restore the data.

Comment: thanks, is a backup of small, but important mysql database, the solution i guess is to use mysqldump with task scheduler and the with DATAPROTECTOR up the information to tape.

Comment: about this : "To minimise downtime (if that's important) you might consider running master-slave replication, and running the backup from the slave (which could reside on the same physical server)"  where can i find more information"

Comment: The manual ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: Google? http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Replication/Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Administrator](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html), part of the ole MySQL GUI Tools Bundle, will let you do this.

Alternatively, you could write a simple batch file that uses mysqldump, and use the Windows Task Scheduler to automate it. An example batch file can be found [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?160,359714,360268#msg-360268).

Comment: thanks for your information, I read more about that tool.